# Multiplas requisições GET com Angular 4/5

Tags: angular

Estou fazendo uma consulta em uma API (SWAPI). O retorno é um objeto com todas as informações dos personagens do Star Wars. Até ai tudo bem.
Só que dentro desse objeto, tenho alguns subniveis que são arrays e que além de algumas informações, também tem uma outra URL que eu preciso consultar para poder imprimir na tela.
O problema é que não estou sabendo como fazer essa outra consulta. Para simplificar, segue a imagem do retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o get do serviço:

```
    getData(page?: string): Observable<any[]> {
    if(page){
      this.URL = page;
    }
    return this.http.get(this.URL)
    .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

Sei que existe uma forma de fazer com flatMap e forkJoin. Eu até tentei, porém não consegui o resultado esperado

Segui esse link:
[rxjs-observable](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/#respond)

Mas mesmo assim não consegui.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada, minha solucao seria usar uma função que te ajudaria e pra uma lista de urls retorna os observables de suas requisições. Depois para cada elemento que tem este array de urls eu chamo a função. Depois so se tem que mapear em ordem de que vc chamou. Eu estou usando o operador pipe dependo da versão do rxjs que vc estiver usando ele não esta disponível ai e so fazer .mergeMap e assim por diante.

**Tenha em mente que com o forkJoin se uma requisição falhar todas falham.**

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

getItems(urls: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return <Observable<Post>> forkJoin(
        urls.map(url=> <Observable<Post>> this.httpClient.get(url))
     ).pipe(concatAll());
}

getData(page?: string): Observable<any[]> {
        if(page){
          this.URL = page;
        }
        return this.http.get(this.URL).pipe(
        mergeMap((person: any) => {
         return forkJoin(
            of(person),
            this.getItems(person.films)
            this.getItems(person.species)
      ),
       map((data: any[]) => {
          let person= data[0];
          let films= data[1];
          let species= data[2];
          person.films= films;
          book.species= species;
          return person;
        })
    }))        
}
```

Comment: Então, ta me dando uns erros estranhos aqui, tipo:  Cannot find name 'from'., no primeiro return. Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' no this.httpClient.get(url), Cannot find name 'forkJoin', Cannot find name 'on'.
Estranho é que estão todos importados

Comment: qual sua versão do rxjs no package.json? Atualiza pra uma maior que 5.5.

Comment: Então, atualizei para a 5.5.10. O map resolvi, tinha colocado uma virgula ao invés de um ponto. No erro do "of, não seria Observable.of(person)? Eu coloquei o Observable.of e o erro sumiu, porém não sei se impactaria, ja o erro do "from" e da URL permanecem :(

Comment: Observable.of também significa que esta uma versão antiga,no entanto todos os operadores que eu usei existem na versões anteriores tbm. So ver como usa-los. tenta Observable.of, Observable.forkJoin. o outro so tirar o pipe e fazer com .

Comment: Então, os erros todos consegui resolver, o problema está mesmo naquele "return from" que diz que não pode achar o nome e na url

Comment: Consegui resolver o "from", agora o problema tá no mergeMap kkkkkk Property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.

Comment: pode usar o of inves do from

Comment: pode usar flatmap que e a mesma coisa que o mergemap

Comment: Então amigo, eu troquei o Observable<Item> por any, e no this.httpClient.get(url) me da esse erro: "Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'." Isso acontece mesmo que eu coloque o meu modelo, da o mesmo erro
E no mergeMap((person: any) me da esse erro: Argument of type '(person: any) => UnaryFunction<Observable<any[]>, Observable<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type...
Já não sei mais o que fazer

Comment: editei ali o get Items, tenta agora.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não vejo problema em usar 2 métodos GET, por exemplo:

E acho que deveria criar 2 interfaces uma para cada retorno ... assim conseguiria pegar o resultado fácil:

```
interface Retono1{

  retorno: number;
  retorno1: string;
  retorno2: string;
  retorno3: string[];
  retorno4: number;

}

retorno:Retorno1;

 this.http.get(this.url)
      .subscribe(result => {
          this.retorno = result.json();
          //primeiro retorno
           this.http.get(this.url)
           .subscribe(result => {

                 //segundo retorno

            })

 });
```

E usaria a lógica para pegar o segundo retorno para uma interface também...